# How to implement the Load Balancing in Openshift ?

Tags: docker, openshift, loadbalancing

I have deployed my application on cloud using Openshift. I tried few blogs but could not find out the best ways to implement the Load Balancing . Please help.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to find the icon that scales the application up and click it. In the current UI it's in Project --> Overview --> expand the application info (">" icon to the left), --> click "^" next to the blue circle to the right.

This gives you a default load-balancing across as many PODs (instances) of the application as your resources and imagination allow.

From the command line, this would scale it to 3 PODs:

```
oc scale --replicas=3 rc yourapplicationname
```

Another way is to deploy the same application with a different name, and then edit the route (Applications --> Routes --> RouteName) that points to it. There should be an option:

> Alternate Services / Split traffic across multiple services

This gives you control over how much traffic you want through each version. Good for A/B testing or canary releases.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I have still seems that in my organistaion many team are using external load balancer  and not using HA proxy and openshift provided load balancing . what would be the reason ?

Comment: The purpose? Maybe they are load balancing across clusters? But I think you better ask directly the teams.